# Retrieve inverse of 0-1 matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ from inverse over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $A\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ be a 0-1 matrix. It may be considered as a matrix over various fields. Let $p$ be a prime. Assume A is invertible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, the finite field with $p$ elements. I believe that in this case $A$ is also invertible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (by considering the determinant, for instance).

My question is: Is there a way to retrieve the inverse of $A$ over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}$) explicitly from the inverse of $A$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: The answer is no; we "lose information" when we take the inverse over $\Bbb F_p$.  However, it should certainly be possible to retrieve the inverse by looking at the inverses over sufficiently many fields $\Bbb F_p$

Comment: We do not have to look at many $p$'s, it suffices to pick one $p$ large enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A} \operatorname{adj}(A)$, it suffices to retrieve $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ over $\mathbb Q$ from $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ over $\mathbb F_p$.

The entries of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ certainly lie between $-\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ and $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$, so just have to pick $p>(n-1)!$ and you have that $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ over $\mathbb F_p$ and $\mathbb Q$ coincide, if you choose the representatives between $-\frac{p}{2}$ and $\frac{p}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if $p$ is a small prime, for instance $p=2$? I find it difficult to gasp how retrieving the inverse over $\mathbb{R}$ can be difficult or impossible while - at the same time - its existence is obvious...

Comment: If $p$ is too small, there is no chance. There are plenty of examples in mathematics, where existence of a certain thing is obvious, but the actual construction is very hard or impossible.